# Six letters to answer this riddle

Tags: riddle

Well guys, hope you will enjoy this one :)

Clue 1:

> Right start

Clue 2:

> Six letters to write

Clue 3:

> Only to guess, nothing more, nothing less

Clue 4:

> A couple united in the middle of the facts

Clue 5:

> End

**Who am I?**

---

**Edit**

Hint 1:

> I need answers, more I get answers, more there's possibility I can consider myself done

Hint 2:

> It's not rare to find myself on this forum

Comment: I just added some hints to make it easier for you, hope you get the answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the world this?

> **Riddle**

Clue 1:

> Because the word "riddle" is to the right of the title

Clue 2:

> R-I-D-D-L-E

Clue 3:

> ''Only To guess'' because the riddle must be guessed

Clue 4:

> Because there is a double **D**: ''RI **(DD)** LE''

Clue 5:

> Is located at the end of the title

Hint 1:

> Because it's possible to find multiple answers to a riddle, right or wrong

Hint 2:

> In this forum there are many riddles

Comment: That's the right answer, nice to see that every clue/hint has a well-explained argumentation. The only thing I didn't see when I created this riddle was about the first and the fifth clues: Right start was meant to the word's initial (R), while End was meant to the word's end (E). Anyway, nice one :)

Answer (score 3):

The word isn't this, is it?

> ARGUES

Clue 1;

> AR = R (AR sounds like R)

Clue 2

> It is a six letter word

Clue 3

> Only to GUESS, removing the duplicates (nothing more, nothing less)

Clue 4

> "United in the middle of the facts" sounds like a debate to me.

Clue 5

> And that's the whole word! AR + GUES

Comment: I liked your fast reasoning, the clues seem to be accurate except for the fourth, as you indicated. However, despite the efforts, that's not the answer (anyway, don't worry: new answers are welcome)